# Websphere Application Server 6.1 (localized): Override locale for console messages

Tags: command-line, internationalization, websphere, optional-parameters, websphere-6.1

I have installed RAD 7.5 (based on Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.0) in Spanish. I'm working with **Websphere Application Server 6.1** (spanish too).

The problem I have is that all console messages appear in Spanish, but translation is, in my personal opinion, quite poor (especially since even the console errors are displayed in Spanish and it's difficult to find documentation about exact error messages).

I want to start the IDE in the original language (English) and I know that there is a command line switch `-nl en` that, placed beside eclipse executable path on program shortcut, serves  for this purpose. But <strike>I'm still getting some resources' labels (e.g. "*Tasks*" tab) into spanish (tab says "*Tareas*"), also</strike> server console still displays messages in spanish.

[UPDATE: Yesterday the client for whom I work, changed my PC for a more powerful one, and the untranslated tabs problem does not occur anymore (the new PC has Windows 7 and the previous one was XP, maybe it's that)]

**My question is: *Does anyone know how I could get WAS console messages displayed 100% in English, overriding locale specified at setup time? Is there some command line switch that serves to get this? Is there any way to edit WAS config files to achieve this?***

Note: It is impossible to reinstall RAD and WAS, because of some restrictions on my computer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Web Console:**

To change web console messages you have to set english as web browser's preferred language.

**Log messages:**

WebSphere logging/tracing mechanism are build upon Java's standard library ResourceBundle/Locale classes.
Localized messages are stored inside WebSphere jars 
(example: com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnMessages_es.class).
So to change the console language you have to change **JVM** default locale's language.

In WebSphere Console:
[Application Server] \ Server Infrastructure \ 
Java and Process Management\
Process definition \
Java Virtual Machine \
Generic JVM arguments

Add parameter : `-Duser.language=US`

This method changes JVM's configuration so it can have impact on you application.

Comment: Thank you! It works nicely: this extra parameter even changes language for right click entries for WAS in eclipse. Take your **+50** for your valuable help.