# WebSphere Portal Server is outputting localized message on console. How to change this?

Tags: localization, message, websphere-portal

I'm using RAD 7.5.0 to develop portlets on IBM WebSphere Portal Server 6.1.0.
When I start the portal server in RAD, it outputs some question mark in messages into console, such as

```
[7/18/12 11:15:36:329 CST] 00000014 SchedulerImpl I   SCHD0032I: Scheduler wps/Scheduler ??????
[7/18/12 11:15:37:815 CST] 00000014 InternalGener I   DSRA8203I: Database ????Apache Derby
[7/18/12 11:15:37:831 CST] 00000014 InternalGener I   DSRA8204I: Database ?????10.1.3.3
```

I checked on another machine, the normal log message should be:

```
[7/17/12 21:03:21:710 CDT] 0000001a SchedulerImpl I   SCHD0032I: The Scheduler wps/Scheduler is initializing.
[7/17/12 21:03:25:382 CDT] 0000001a InternalGener I   DSRA8203I: Database product name : Apache Derby
[7/17/12 21:03:25:382 CDT] 0000001a InternalGener I   DSRA8204I: Database product version : 10.1.3.3
```

My PC's language was set to Chinese, so I suppose it's trying to output some Chinese localized message. But even after I changed my language setting into English, the message wasn't changed.

I also tried the solution in [Websphere Application Server 6.1 (localized): Override locale for console messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666916/websphere-application-server-6-1-localized-override-locale-for-console-messag)
And it didn't solve my problem.

I also noticed that the first half part of log messages are outputted normally in English, while another part which seems relate to the services is abnormal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by changing the portal server setting to English:
Administration -> Portal Settings -> Global Settings -> Default portal language